# How to stop fallback from H+ to 3G data

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, data-connection, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

**Is it possible, and if so how, to lock the phone to using H+ for data and not dropping back to 3G?** I suspect it isn't (firmware of the radio hardware I'm guessing) but there's times where I would be willing to take the battery hit to keep my data on H+ (specific application with data demands that doesn't like dropping back and forwards to 3G).

**I'm not talking about changes in signal quality:** I can be sitting in a single location, not moving, where both H+ and 3G are available. When data is being requested the phone typically goes to H+ as it is faster. Once the data demands reduce it drops back to 3G. I have read in a number of other places that this is on purpose to save battery. However my issue is that one app I use doesn't handle the transitions well so I'd like to stop the auto-fallback.

Android 4.2.2 on Samsung Galaxy S4 mini, Australian networks.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've integrated it with your original question (and removed my comment, as it got obsoleted by those details), to make it more obvious. Which means, we can remove these two comments then as well :) The answer, however, I have to defer to someone else. As you already did, I suspect that being dealt with by the radio or at least deep in the core. From your description, it might be related to [fast dormancy](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/674208-fast-dormancy-in-nutshell.html), but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: That cannot be done, baseband chip determines signal from nearby masts, continuously scanning depending on area you are in. That is outside of control of your device, no can do. The battery saver is in regards to using 2G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do and it worked for me is download the [HSPA+ Tweaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BBsRs.HSPAP.Tweaker) from google play store.

I dont know for sure but i think it works by sending extra data packages to trick the provider into thinking you are in need of a higher and faster connection, thus making your phone stay on H+ rather than dropping down to 3g or less.

I had the exact same problem and it is now sorted with this app.

It may use extra data but it is worth it when you need a quick boost, if you have unlimited data allowance you are laughing really.

you can switch the app off within a swipe and a tap so it really is an all round handy app.